# Accumulation point of Complex Number Set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $S = \{ (1 + i)(\omega_7)^n \vert n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $\omega_7 = exp (i \frac{2 \pi}{7})$. Show that $S$ is the collection of all $7$th roots of a complex number $z_o = a + bi$. What is the complex number $z_0$? Determine the accumulation points of the set $S$.

I have shown $S$ is the collection of all $7$th roots of the complex number $z_0 = a + bi$ and also find out $z_0$. But I am confused on the accumulation point of the set $S$. My idea is:

When $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $S$ will always have $7$ elements inside it only which is the $7$th roots. So I want to find a point that each of the distance between these $7$th roots and the accumulation point is the shortest. Then since these $7$complex numbers is on complex plane so is it concluded that the origin is the accumulation point?

Need someone's help, thanks for reading this question.

Comment: A finite set in $\mathbb C$ has no accumulation points.

Comment: @hff Is it because there will have some deleted neighborhood of accumulation point a such that they have not contains any points of S?

Comment: Yes, take a neighborhood with a radius less than the minimum of the distances between a point and the points in $s$.